# Open Weather Api multiple locations?

Tags: jquery, openweathermap

I'm using open weather api for displaying weather, but i need to display weather for multiple location. Any suggestion?

```
function getWeather(callback) {
    var weather = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Zagreb&&APPID=08dbab0eeefe53317d2e0ad7c2a2e060';
    $.ajax({
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: weather,
      success: callback
    });
}
```

This is how i display weather for only one city, but i dont know how to pass more cities?!

Comment: How many locations? Will other locations be added?

Comment: i need 8 locations ... yes they will be addeed i need to display them

Comment: You can make 8 different queries, if there is not a lot of users. If there is a lot of users, I'd store that information somewhere in order to reduce the amount of queries, and then query from the stored information (for a limited time, of course)

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to get the city id for each one you want to call, which can be found here:

http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/city.list.us.json.gz
http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/city.list.json.gz

Then, per the API docs found here https://openweathermap.org/current#severalid you can use the following code to call the data for multiple cities at once:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=524901,703448,2643743&units=metric
```

Comment: unfortunately this function is no longer supported :/ there is no clue about it on docs.